# How to get a double line subset symbol, (but not \Subset)?

Tags: symbols

The symbol I'm looking for appears in maths when the closure of an open set is contained in a bigger set; it's like two `\subset`, but doesn't look like `\Subset`. It's similar to `\ll`. How can I typeset that symbol?

Some code showing the different symbols discussed above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\string\subset  & $\subset$ \\
\string\Subset  & $\Subset$ \\
\string\ll          & $\ll$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen the notation used in Rudin's book “Real and complex analysis”. Perhaps, simply doubling `\subset` is too crude. Here's a possible solution, top line is `\subset\subset`, bottom line `\ssubset` defined with some backspace between the two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ssubset}{\subset\joinrel\subset}

\begin{document}
$A\subset\subset B$

$A\ssubset B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be quite similar to `\ll`, then you can use this symbol, which overlaps the two `\subset`s. It should work properly in all sizes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\ssubset{
  \mathrel{
    \mathrlap{\subset}
    \hphantom{\ll}
    \mathllap{\subset}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
  A\ssubset B_{A\ssubset B_{A\ssubset B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

In the above code I wrote it on several lines to show a bit what's going on. The one-liner works as well of course:

```
\newcommand\ssubset{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\subset}\hphantom{\ll}\mathllap{\subset}}}
```