# Writting text below the "subset" symbol

Tags: symbols

`$A \subseteq B$`. I want to write "bounded" below the `\subseteq` symbol. How can I do it?

I found a way to write text above and below an arrow symbol. But how to do the same with the subset symbol?

Comment: Consider [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\underset`. See [How to add text under symbol in equation ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40217/5764)

Comment: You got your answer in Werner's comment, but since the word "bounded" is fairly long, I'd probably try to avoid writing it below `\subseteq` since it pushes the two sets away from the symbol. Since it will additionally set up your line heights, I would try to avoid even shorter forms like "bdd." in inline math. I would probably just write what you need to say in words. If this is a recurring and important concept you may be able to define a symbol for it. I have seen `\Subset` used for a compact set contained in another, but there are other similarly-shaped symbols ...

Comment: ... (see the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list on CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) or you roll your own symbol like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22371/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147439/35864.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `\clap` command from `mathtools`, you can have the default spacing of `\subset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
 A \underset{\clap{\scriptsize bounded}}{\subseteq}B \]

\end{document}
```

[image]